# An equivalent definition for set equality using tautology

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory

We known from logic that,
$$\left(p\Leftrightarrow q\right)\Leftrightarrow\left(\sim p \Leftrightarrow \sim q\right)$$
is a *tautology,* so when we see the definition of equality of sets,
$$\left(A = B\right) \Leftrightarrow \forall x \left(x\in A \Leftrightarrow x\in B\right)$$
we have an iff statement, so using our tautology should be possible.

I'm trying to figure out if the next proposition is an equivalence definition for the equality of set.

$$\left(A = B\right) \Leftrightarrow \forall x(x\not\in A \Leftrightarrow x\not\in B)$$

We get that proposition negating both  $\in$ from the original definition.

---

so my questions are:

1. Is the last proposition true?
2. And if is not, why is it?

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip I think you're looking at the wrong if and only if. If $A = B$ then every element not in $A$ is not in $B$, and every element not in $B$ is not in $A$. For the converse, if every element not in $A$ is not in $B$ _and_ every element not in $B$ is not in $A$, then it is true that $A = B$. In your example, you have $2$ not in $B$ does not imply that $2$ is not in $A$, failing the hypothesis.

Comment: @Bill Withdrawn.

Comment: You need parentheses around the *scope* of the quantified x

Answer (score 0):

This is true, and could be a good exercise for you. Take my comment (below) as a sketch proof, and see if you can work through the details.

> If $A=B$ then every element not in $A$ is not in $B$, and every element not in $B$ is not in $A$. For the converse, if every element not in $A$ is not in $B$ *and* every element not in $B$ is not in $A$, then it is true that $A=B$.

Note that $A = \{1, 2\}$ and $B = \{1\}$ is not a valid counterexample. Try to understand why --- this will help with your own proof.